# Does std::find implicitly fix invalid arguments?

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector

So I have the really weird situation, that a program of mine is *working* when, to my understanding, there's no way it should. This question is therefore just because I want to get better understanding about the backgrounds of what I'm doing (because I'm really confused at the moment).

So suppose I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Foo{
private:
  string s;
public:
  Foo(string s);
};
```

I have a vector containing elements of this class, like this:

```
vector<Foo> myFoos = {...};
```

Now, I wanted to find the index of an element of `myFoos` knowing the content of the string. Here's what I was meaning to code:

```
string toBeSearched = "something";
vector<Foo>::iterator it = find(myFoos.begin(),myFoos.end(),Foo(toBeSearched));
unsigned int index = distance(myFoos.begin(),it);
```

But I accidentally messed up the `find()`and passed an object of the type `String` instead of `Foo`:

```
find(myFoos.begin(),myFoos.end(),toBeSearched);
```

However, everything still worked just like I wanted it to, giving me the correct location of the object containing the `toBeSearched`-string. It exceeds my understanding, why that is. When the `find()` function runs, it would need to check for equality between the search parameter and the vector's elements. However, I didn't define any equality relation between `String` and `Foo` (I did write an overload of the == operator to check for equality between two `Foo`'s). Therefore, such a comparison shouldn't be possible. The only theory I can come up with is that the function searches for a suitable constructor and creates a `Foo`(suitable data-type) from the `String` (incorrect data-type). However, that would be really weird behaviour in my eyes. Also, I'd expect a statically typed language like C++ to not even compile in the first place when I happen to pass an argument of a wrong type like here.
What does `std::find()` internally do with the arguments that it's given to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ allows for "user defined" implicit conversions.

Basically, because there's a `Foo` constructor that takes a `string`, and you attempted to use a `string` in place of a `Foo`, it decided to do a conversion for you by passing the `string` into `Foo`'s constructor, which created an instance of `Foo`.

From [CPPReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> A user-defined conversion consists of zero or one non-explicit single-argument constructor or non-explicit conversion function call
>
> An expression e is said to be implicitly convertible to T2 if and only if T2 can be copy-initialized from e, that is the declaration T2 t = e; is well-formed (can be compiled), for some invented temporary t. Note that this is different from direct initialization (T2 t(e)), where explicit constructors and conversion functions would additionally be considered.

You can add the `explicit` keyword to a constructor to prevent it from being used in an implicit conversion.

Comment: I have to admit though, part of that quote has me confused: "... An expression e is said to be implicitly convertible to T2 if and only if T2 can be copy-initialized from e, that is the declaration T2 t = e" is well-formed". I wouldn't expect `Foo f = "some string";` to be valid though. The behavior the OP describes must be because of an implicit conversion, but I can't see why such a conversion would have been allowed to happen in the first place.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I think that the implicit conversion happens for each comparison. Since the definition of find is (according to [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find]):

`template< class InputIt, class T >
InputIt find( InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value );`

`std::string` will be a perfect match for `T` and hence no conversion will happen when passing the string. Only when calling `operator==` inside `find` the conversion will become necessary and thus performed for every element.

Comment: @sv90 is correct: `std::find` deduces the template argument to be `std::string`, but then inside `find`, overload resolution on an expression like `*iter == value` finds `operator==(const Foo&, const Foo&)` because `string` can implicitly convert to `Foo`.

Comment: @aschepler Damn, C++ is confusing. It figures my 10k answer is for something I only thinly understand. Glad you guys could verify it.

Comment: `T t = x;` is defined as `T t = T(x);` if `T` is not related to the type of `x`.  It is the same reason you can write `std::string s = "some string";` even though `"some string"` is not a `std::string`. Similarly, `float f = 1;`